# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity

Tags: android

[image]I am a beginner on Android, I have added a splash screen on my app, but app crashes after the splash screen displaying "Unfortunately "app" has stop working
I have attached the logcat screenshot

[image]

Comment: You have to declare your activities in manifest.xml.

Comment: It will be nice if you can post your Manifest.XML file and perhaps the Activity that is throwing the error?

Comment: If you notise, the error is asking If you decalre your MainActivity in Manifest? So where is your Manifest.XML so people can help you locate and fix the bug

Comment: I have attached the manifest file now

Comment: I have declared both activities in manifest

Comment: Move the category LAUNCHER AND MAIN into the intentFilter tag inside the Activity tag of your MainActivity.  It would have been easy to edit it for if it was text as opposed to screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did declare both Activities, but for **two different applications**! Put the `MainActivity` declaration into the first *application* tag, just like you did with the `Splash` one, and remove the other *application* tag.